# "Execution failed for task ':A_CERTAIN_MODULE:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'" while building project, after gradle update

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Today, the android studio told me that the Gradle for my project can be updated to 7.0.2. This is where my misery begins...

The Gradle was successfully updated. But when I tried to debug the app, an error occurred:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':awesome_notifications:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleLibraryClassesWorkAction
   > Zip file '[PATH_TO_PROJECT]\build\awesome_notifications\intermediates\compile_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar' already contains entry 'me/carda/awesome_notifications/AwesomeNotificationsPlugin.class', cannot overwrite
```

I spent hours trying to fix it. I have tried many things: restarting the IDE, flutter clean, invalidate caches restart, deleting the .gradle folder, etc.
So I decided to remove the package, and as expected, the error above was not shown, instead, some unknown import error was shown which is obvious since I was using the package on my codes. Next, I re-add the package to the dependencies and run pub get, and when I tried to debug the app, once again, the above error was shown.

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

I don't know whether this error is related to that particular package, or the gradle. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the gradle version in build.gradle file. It could be that your package is dependent on the previous gradle version so try reverting it back to the old one.